Esiste il ‘vesre’ in italiano?
Gli ispanoparlanti rioplatensi hanno il vesre. È un fenomeno che consiste nella trasposizione delle sillabe (eventualmente con qualche lettera modificata o spostata). Esempi di vesre sono: lleca (calle), feca (café), zapi (pizza), telo (hotel), nami (mina), jermu (mujer), bolonqui (quilombo), topu (puto), dolobu (boludo). Può essere anche più complesso, come brocacochi (cabro chico). Anche vesre è un vesre.
C'è qualcosa del genere in italiano? Girate le parole, almeno per divertimento?

Sarebbe, tipo un anagramma? https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagramma

@RiccardoDeContardi Non è solamente  un anagramma. La trasposiszione è intenzionale e la parola trasposta ha uguale significato che la originale (è un argot).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riocontra ?

@n.m.couldbeanAI Epico. Perché non elabori una risposta così guadagni alcuni punti?

Sono solo uno studente principiante di italiano. per me sarebbe un po' difficile scrivere una risposta completa.
